# What is server side java script? Can we use java script also at server side? Which type of java script is necessary to know for a front-end developer?

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

I just read that there is also a type of java script called **server-side java script**, before it i was thinking that java script is used only at client side....so my question is what is server-side java script ...and for a front-end develoer , is it necessary to learn both types of java script?

Comment: It is called **JavaScript**, one word not two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server side java script is somehow like java/C++/.Net/ruby/php... It is just an approach of programming server code. If you work on the front-end without any back-end work to do, it is not necessarily to learn server-side java script. Server side java script you mentioned is probably nodejs. Imagine that you can write a server with js instead of java or php.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript is a programming language, it can be run in a number of different environments.  Most people run into it in browsers but it can also be used at the command-line via [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) or currently on the server-side using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) Since it's inception back in 1996 [JavaScript has been able to run on the server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript).

There aren't different 'kinds' of JavaScript, the syntax and built-in language constructs remain the same no matter what environment you are in. However different environments may provide APIs for functionality that is not available in other environments.  For instance, in the browser you have the `window` and `document` objects, in Rhino or Node.js these interfaces are absent, but they support other features that a browser based implementation does not.

If you are a front-end web developer it is important to know about `window`, `document` and other browser specific APIs, but you don't need to know about the features offered in other environments.

Answer (score 1):

An example of server-side javascript is [Nodejs](http://nodejs.org/). It's a javascript api that runs on Google's V8 javascript engine and is used for even-based IO. It's popular application is for making web servers. As a front end dev it's not necessary to learn it - there are lots of javascript libraries you could learn, but the main applications for this particular one aren't for front-end engineering.

That said, it's pretty nifty to tinker around with.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably referring to `node.js`

http://nodejs.org/

It would definitely not be necessary for a front-end developer to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several instances of server-side JavaScript these days, like

- [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), which allows to implement in JavaScript what otherwise would be typically done with Servlets or PHP or ASP or...; and
- some [databases](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/816-6411-10/contents.htm) support embedding JavaScript
- possibly more instances...

After alle, JavaScript is just a language, and with a appropriate runtime you can use it for almost anything (which does not necessarily mean that you *should* do that). For a front-end developer it is not strictly necessary to know these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is server side javascript.

Node.js:-Node.js is an open source, cross-platform runtime environment for developing server-side and networking applications. Node.js applications are written in JavaScript, and can be run within the Node.js runtime on OS X, Microsoft Windows, and Linux.

If you want to become a javascript Front End developer then you must know about basic javascript,ES6 and you can Choose anyone  Front end Technology React or Angular for become a Front End Developer.